# intercept the audio stream that is playing on a pc Java

Tags: java, audio-recording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [internal audio recording program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514028/internal-audio-recording-program)

Here is the scenario: You are listening a song or an audio file with windows media player or vlc or from youtube whatever... i want that my program intercept the audio stream for analyze it. I tried to look at java documentation with no success. Do you have any advice ? or better some code example? 
Thank you for reading and for the aswers

Answer (score 0):

There is no routines in the standard Java Runtime Library to intercept audio streams at the operating system level, so you cannot do what you want to do directly.

You will need a third-party program that looks to Windows as a sound unit but provides the data to e.g. you instead of converting it to actual sound.

Comment: third-party program that looks to Windows as a sound unit but provides the data to e.g. you instead of converting it to actual sound. Do you know one of them ? just to try ... :)

Comment: sorry no, but that is what I would look for if I were you.

Comment: Thanks i'll try to find something :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved by setting the record source of my pc to the mixer on Audiosetting in Control Panel